# document.getelementById doesn't work on dynamically generated divs

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, dynamically-generated

I am trying to update the content of a dynamically generated div with .innerHTML and getElementById, but when I test it, I get an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" I also tried using alert() and checking the value of quizDiv at breakpoints. Well, here's my JS file called main.js:

```
function makeDiv() {
document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='quizDiv'></div>"
}
function createInputBox(boxId) {
     var quizDiv = document.getElementById("quizDiv");
     quizDiv.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='" + boxId + "'>";
 }
makeDiv();
createInputBox(1);
```

Here's my html:

```
<!-- doctype, head, etc -->
<body>
<!-- content -->
<script src="/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting that error in line 2 or 6?

Comment: The code could be running before the DOM is ready. Try your function calls within window.onload.

Comment: I agree with Crowcoder, this works if fiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/ptzcfdjj/

Comment: @Bergi I'm getting the error on line 6

Comment: @40Alpha: However, it [works without onload just as well](http://jsfiddle.net/ptzcfdjj/1/)

Comment: @Bergi, I did noticed that. I just ran it locally on my machine. Exact code from above, it works. Not sure what is wrong... Timothy is all code included in your question? What browser are you using?

Comment: @Crowcoder window.onload won't work because window.onload fires when the page loads not when the page is changed (like replacing the body with a div).

Comment: @40Alpha I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: Well, this code works perfectly for all of us, the problem surely comes from other code you haven't posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already creating the div in js, why not hold the reference then?

```
function makeDiv() {
    var quizDiv=document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(quizDiv);
    return quizDiv;
}
function createInputBox(quizDiv,boxId) {
     // var quizDiv = document.getElementById("quizDiv");
     quizDiv.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='" + boxId + "'>";
 }
var quizDiv=makeDiv();
createInputBox(quizDiv,1);
```

Comment: Or even better, return it and pass it as a parameter to that create function.

Comment: as @Bergi commented, that was some bad coding, updated the example

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with you code.

Firstly the HTML is not valid, meaning ID's can't start with numbers. Read more about how to overcome this issue here: [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/)

Secondly, you code 'works' could you provide an image of your directory structure and the full markup? Here is a jsfiddle with your code and it displays the input: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3tan0tw9/) Maybe there is a problem with the file path or your calling the js file before the document is ready.

I cleaned your code up a bit so maybe try this instead:

```
window.onload = function () {

    var body = document.body;

    function createDiv (identifier) {
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.id = identifier;

        body.appendChild(el);
    }

    function createInput(identifier) {
        var div = document.getElementById('quizDiv');
        div.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='" + identifier + "'>";
    }

    createDiv('quizDiv');
    createInput('bar');
};
```